# Program runs, calls function but I get no "output" on STM32L1

Tags: c, arm, stm32, keil

I encounter a problem currently with a custom STM32L151 board that I will try to explain here.
The program I am testing runs properly for some time, I get debug messages on puTTY as intended but at a time, the program seems to be "blocked".

It is pretty weird behaviour because the function which prints over UART is called (I put a breakpoint here to see if I reach this point) but I get no output on a terminal.

So I was wondering what could be the issue, if someone as an idea because I kinda run out of ideas to be honest, I tried to understand. I will assume there is no hardware issue, it is still possible but I do not think it could be that reason.

Also, the programs is aimed at receiving a FSK message and answering it and it seems that I have the same behaviour with the radio chip: I receive the message and send a response (I get the TxDone callback called which indicates that the FSK message has normally been sent but the device which waits for this response does not receive it).

So to sum up a bit: the program runs properly for a moment then "blocks" & I do not get any output anymore (debug or radio communication) but still runs (functions effectively called) and after a moment again, the program "unblocks" itself and runs properly again (debug messages work).

The device I work on is STM32L151 based, I work with Keil, UART config is: 19200 baudrate, 8 data bits, 1 stop bit, no parity, XON/XOFF flow control & the radio chip I use is SX1272.
If someone has any idea or any trail I can investigate on. If you need any further details, I am not sure I am accurate enough on the description of the problem but any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is there a piece of sample code you could include with this question? It may speed up getting your answer. Good luck 

Comment: Some debuggers that display raw memory maps or hardware peripheral registers can eat up status flags for UART or SPI, particularly when single-stepping. This applies to hardware peripherals of the kind that have status flag registers that are cleared by reading the memory. If this is the case, the problem will go away when you download to flash and restart without the debugger attached.

Comment: @Lundin I thought about that, it can be that but it seems that when I don't use the debugger, the radio issue still occurs and I cannot get the response on other devices who expect the answer, I need to test without debugger but UART still linked to see if the behaviour still occurs without debugger

Comment: Since the program "unblocks" itself, is it going into low power mode? Have you looked at the possibility that exiting low power mode, presumably via an interrupt, is being inhibited in some way?

Comment: Maybe there is noise on the line.  For instance, a break character or parity error.  The driver may not handle this and the communication link blocks up.  I have seen PC comm ports that are very flaky.  Sometime the problem isn't with your device but PC hardware.  Although you seem to have the issue with two UART ports so that might not be your case.  There may also be voltage issues.  You need to check the UART status bits and get a scope on some lines.  You will see voltage changes, noise and clock changes with the scope to quickly find/eliminate common issues.

Comment: without a code we are just shooting in the dark, guessing.  Please post the needed [mcve]